# How to preserve the order of items emitted by two observables after they are merged?

Tags: scala, observable, rx-java, reactivex, rx-scala

I have run into a behavior of Scala Observables that has surprised me. Consider my example below:

```
object ObservablesDemo extends App {

  val oFast = Observable.interval(3.seconds).map(n => s"[FAST] ${n*3}")
  val oSlow = Observable.interval(7.seconds).map(n => s"[SLOW] ${n*7}")
  val oBoth = (oFast merge oSlow).take(8)

  oBoth.subscribe(println(_))
  oBoth.toBlocking.toIterable.last

}
```

The code demonstrates emitting elements from two observables. One of them emits its elements in a "slow" way (every 7 seconds), the other in a "fast" way (every 3 seconds). For the sake of the question assume we want to define those observables with the use of the `map` function and map the numbers from the `interval` appropriately as seen above (as opposed to another possible approach which would be emitting items at the same rate from both observables and then `filter`ing out as needed).

The output of the code seems counterintuitive to me:

```
[FAST] 0
[FAST] 3
[SLOW] 0
[FAST] 6
[FAST] 9   <-- HERE
[SLOW] 7   <-- HERE
[FAST] 12
[FAST] 15
```

The problematic part is when the `[FAST]` observable emits `9` before the `[SLOW]` observable emits `7`. I would expect `7` to be emitted before `9` as whatever is emitted on the seventh second should come before what is emitted on the ninth second.

How should I modify the code to achieve the intended behavior? I have looked into the RxScala documentation and have started my search with topics such as the different `interval` functions and the `Scheduler` classes but I'm not sure if it's the right place to search for the answer.

Comment: I would suggest using something like **fs2**, **Monix**, **AkkaStreams** or **ZIO** over **RxScala**. There is also the library that uses **Laminar** under the hood _(**outwatch** I believe is called)_.

Comment: The thing is that your fast observable is starting at `3rd` second and slow starts at `7th` second. So, `9` is emited at by fast at`12th` second where as `7` is emitted by slow at `14th` second.

Comment: You need to use `Observable.interval(0.seconds, 3.seconds)` and `Observable.interval(0.seconds, 7.seconds)` to start your observables at `0th` second.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like the way it should work.  Here it is listing out the seconds and the events. You can verify with `TestObserver` and `TestScheduler` if that is available in RXScala. RXScala was EOL in 2019, so keep that in mind too.

```
Secs   Event
-----------------
1
2
3      [Fast] 0
4
5
6      [Fast] 3
7      [Slow] 0
8
9      [Fast] 6
10
11
12     [Fast] 9
13
14     [Slow] 7
15     [Fast] 12
16
17
18     [Fast] 15
19
20
21     [Fast] 18
```